# Laravel - Controlador return view->width nao passa dados para a view

Tags: php, laravel

Minha view nao possui os dados enviados pelo user

**Controlador**

```
$posts = Models::post()->with('user')
                       ->where('chatter_discussion_id', '=', $discussion->id)
                       ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
                       ->paginate(10); 
return view('chatter::discussion', compact('discussion', 'posts', 'corretor'));
```

**Model**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'chatter_post';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $fillable = ['chatter_discussion_id', 'user_id', 'body'];

    public function discussion()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Models::className(Discussion::class), 
                               'chatter_discussion_id');
    }
```

**View**

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
//post->user nao tem nada é null
```

Comment: Que isso mano: `Models::className(Discussion::class)`?

Answer (score 0):

Seu controller está errado segue a alteração e faça um teste por favor.

```
$posts = Post::with('user')
                   ->where('chatter_discussion_id', '=', $discussion->id)
                   ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
                   ->paginate(10);

return view('chatter::discussion', compact('discussion', 'posts', 'corretor'));
```